# get current time based on timezoneid in javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone

Is there any way to get the current  time for a particular timezone (`ex: var currentTime=getCurrentTime(timezoneId)` where  timezoneId="alaska" or Eastern Time), including Day Light Saving in javascript.

Comment: What timeZoneIds will you be using? UTC time zones, US states, Country Names?

Answer (score 2):

Timezone handling isn't built into JavaScript, so you'd need a library containing all the timezone details (usually generated from the Olson database). eg. [fleegix.date](http://js.fleegix.org/plugins/date/date) has one.

See also [How do I determine the system's Olson zoneinfo in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608423/how-do-i-determine-the-systems-olson-zoneinfo-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6016329.html) looks like a solution, although it uses city names as references.

Comment: It also requires you to know the GMT offset of each timezone.