# How do I get a user's date/time or timezone information for an Alexa Skill?

Tags: datetime, timezone, alexa-skills-kit

I'm using Lambda (Python) to develop a skill and I'm interested in giving the user some time-related information. On the `request` object there is a `timestamp` but that is UTC without offset. Is there a way to find the user's date/time or timezone without having to ask for location information (and if that's the only way, do you know of a database of US zip codes to timezone or another workaround?).

Comment: This will help with the zip-to-timezone question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456324/mapping-us-zip-code-to-time-zone

Comment: Zip code is really not a great way to set time zone.  Especially if you want to handle customers outside the US.

Comment: @MattJohnson agreed, and I see how it will become a burden if I ever deploy to other regions (like the UK, but luckily, they have only one time zone there) but I don't see any other option for the time being.

Comment: Don't know a whole lot about Alexa Skills, but if there's a way to get a zip code, is there also a way to get just a lat/lon or other location info?  If so, there are APIs to translate lat/lon to time zone here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/634824

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks, currently there are only two options: Country+Zip OR Full street address.

Comment: Perhaps try a geocoding API like Google's?  You can then go after the time zone from there. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

Comment: If anyone is interested in this, there is a feature request in the Amazon forums here: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/8857/get-timezone.html#answer-76016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now possible to get the user's timezone using the [Alexa Settings API](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/alexa-settings-api-reference.html). See the related [blogpost](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/c2ba44fa-4bd8-4b49-925d-29dbc0330b1e/personalize-your-alexa-skill-with-customer-specific-time-zones-and-measurements-using-the-alexa-settings-api) for official information about this feature's release.

The endpoint you'll be interested in is the following:

```
GET /v2/devices/{deviceId}/settings/System.timeZone
```

You simply need to provide the user's device ID, which is part of the received intent. The response will contain a [timezone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), for instance "Europe/London".