# How to get the time zone or local time of Alexa device

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone, alexa-skills-kit

I want to get the "time zone" set in the [settings](https://ibb.co/frkM2o) or local date time of the Alexa device. Is there any API available for it? Or is there any option to get the date-time of the user using his postal code?

Any help will be highly appreciable?

Comment: which language are you using for your lambda function?

Comment: There is a [UserVoice](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/33147373-provide-device-timezone-in-alexa-requests) item on this.  Have you seen it?

Comment: Gone thru this, it didn't work. My lambda is in node js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a user's date/time or timezone information for an Alexa Skill?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072625/how-do-i-get-a-users-date-time-or-timezone-information-for-an-alexa-skill)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a native Alexa API that you can use. Here is a perfect solution for what you're looking for. What you will need is a device ID and an API access token. Also, few tools like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) ( npm i axios) and [zip-to-country-code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zipcode-to-timezone) (npm i zipcode-to-timezone) more info here [Enhance Your Skill With Address Information](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html) Also, before you implement this code make sure to go to Alexa dev portal and turn on permissions See image below. Cheers! [image]

```
            const apiAccessToken = this.event.context.System.apiAccessToken;
            const deviceId = this.event.context.System.device.deviceId;
            let countryCode = '';
            let postalCode = '';

            axios.get(`https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/devices/${deviceId}/settings/address/countryAndPostalCode`, {
              headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiAccessToken}` }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                countryCode = response.data.countryCode;
                postalCode = response.data.postalCode;
                const tz = ziptz.lookup( postalCode );
                const currDate = new moment();
                const userDatetime = currDate.tz(tz).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
                console.log('Local Timezone Date/Time::::::: ', userDatetime);
            })
```

Answer (score 5):

It is now possible to get a user's timezone and other related data using the [Alexa Settings API](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/alexa-settings-api-reference.html). Also see the related [blogpost](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/c2ba44fa-4bd8-4b49-925d-29dbc0330b1e/personalize-your-alexa-skill-with-customer-specific-time-zones-and-measurements-using-the-alexa-settings-api) for more information on this API release.

The endpoint you'll be interested in is the following:

```
GET /v2/devices/{deviceId}/settings/System.timeZone
```

You simply need to provide the user's device ID, which is part of the received intent. The response will contain a timezone name, for instance "Europe/London".

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ASK sdk v2. There's a better way to get the timezone.

```
const getCurrentDate = async (handlerInput) => {
    const serviceClientFactory = handlerInput.serviceClientFactory;
    const deviceId = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.device.deviceId;

    try {
        const upsServiceClient = serviceClientFactory.getUpsServiceClient();
        return userTimeZone = await upsServiceClient.getSystemTimeZone(deviceId);   
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.name !== 'ServiceError') {
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak("There was a problem connecting to the service.").getResponse();
        }
        console.log('error', error.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: ^ This works easily. You can also get it from the Cake Time example that Amazon provides. Don't forget to add this line at the top of your exports.handler: 

.withApiClient(new Alexa.DefaultApiClient())