# How to get timezone from lat long or zip code where tzwhere is not a option

Tags: python, python-2.7, aws-lambda

As `tzwhere` is taking a longer time to run on `Serverless`, how do I get the proper `timezone` which supports daylight savings. I need to pass in either `latitude` and `longitude` or the `zipcode` to find the `timezone`, say, `'US/Eastern'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping US zip code to time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456324/mapping-us-zip-code-to-time-zone)

Comment: @Usernamenotfound I'd close this as a duplicate, except that there might be a solution based on Lat/Long too. None of the answers at that question are ideal.

Comment: @Mark - Lat Long are my priority. I dont want to use tzwhere as it has to loop through the entire tz_world file which is not a preferable solution on AWS Lambda.

Comment: Too bad you don't have IP address. I have IP-->Lat/Long-->Timezone working in a Lambda via [IP2Location](http://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-zipcode-timezone). You may be able to get their free CSV version and make it do your bidding. But I am not proposing this as an answer because you don't have IP. So to the point from @MarkRansom — another "not ideal" answer lol