# Convert zipcode, country, state to timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have set of user data (zip code, country, state and city) and I need to figure-out user timezone.
There are example about using google api for zip code, but I don't want include them in to my project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping US zip code to time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456324/mapping-us-zip-code-to-time-zone) It's not exact, but it should get you started.

Comment: this is old topic

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's old. It sill applies. There is no in-built JS API for this information. So the other option is to use a library.