# PHP : getting Timezone offset from user side and calculate "time ago"

Tags: php, time, timezone

I am trying to calculate time passed since a comment is posted. I found a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2916189/996652) for this and it's working well

But I just noticed the time shown to user is wrong because of his/her **timezone**. I did some research and the solution seems to be **passing** the user's timezone offset to the php page using a javascript function called `getTimezoneOffset`.

the problem is that I can't manage to use this Offset to make a timezone and use it on that function I linked above. With the help of [another code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10254751/996652) is what I could gather so far :

```
function humanTiming ($time,$offset)
{

    $isDST = 1; // Daylight Saving 1 - on, 0 - off
    $timezoneName = timezone_name_from_abbr('', intval($offset, 10) * 36, $isDST);

    $date = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($timezoneName));
    $time = strtotime($date);

    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment

    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }

}
```

And let's call the function like this :

```
echo humanTiming ($row['date'],"-240");
```

note : `-240` is the value I get from running that javascript function, So it is probably my timezone offset.

**First issue**: It seems the value `-240`is invalid and something like `-0500` works.

**Second issue**: even If I try with the valid offset value, the function returns `42 years`

Not sure how this 42 years is calculated but its totally wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of problems: 
The Javascript function [`getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) returns the timezone offset in minutes, however [`timezone_name_from_abbr()`](http://www.php.net/timezone_name_from_abbr) expects the offset in seconds. So in your example of `-240` that is actually `-4` hours or `-14396` seconds. You can fix your code by changing the math a little:

```php
$timezoneName = timezone_name_from_abbr('', intval($offset) * 60, $isDST);
```

Since you've started using the `DateTime` object, you can't then use `strtotime` to get the Unix timestamp. Instead you need [`format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

```
$date = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($timezoneName));
$time = $date->format('U');
```

This should get the result you are after. You were getting 42 years because the time was set to 0 (`strtotime($date)` evaluated to false) which is Unix epoch - 1970.

Comment: I changed the code according to your post, now the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: I think something is wrong with time ago function itself, the offset and timestamp problems are fixed. Thanks a lot. It seems it doesn't calculate for anything since few hours ago, or maybe few minutes ago. Not sure why. Math issues :P

Comment: ok After doing a lot of test and trials, the problem was the offset. It had to be a positive number. so multiplied it by `-1`. Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 0):

You could offset everything like so:

```
$today=new DateTime("-$offset minutes");
$tomorrow=new DateTime("+1 day-$offset minutes");
```